# Button is not working in IPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iphone, ipad

```
<input type="button" class="btnlarge green-btn marleft5" onclick="UpdateInfo();" value="Update" id="UpdateButton" />
```

This is my Buttton, on click of that button below function is call.

```
function UpdateInfo()
        {
            var currCheckInID = $("#selectedCheckInId").val();               
            if(!validateInfo()) return;
            try {
                var retVal = "";
                var urlCreate = "./GenericHandler.ashx?method=UpdateParentInformation&checkInID=" + $("#selectedCheckInId").val() + "&parentLocationID=" + $('#<%= DRPParentLocation.ClientID %>').val() + "&handyPhoneID=" + $('#<%= DRPHandyPhones.ClientID %>').val() + "&cabinNumber=" +  $("#txtCabinNo").val() + "&IConciergeNumber=" + $("#txtIConciergeNo").val() + "&childGuestID=" + $("#selectedChildGuestId").val() + "&OldparentLocationID=" + Old_parentlocation + "&OldhandyPhoneID=" + Old_HandyPhone + "&OldcabinNumber=" + Old_CabinNumber + "&OldIConciergeNumber=" + Old_iConciergeNo;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: urlCreate,
                    contentType: "text/ ",
                    dataType: "",
                    success: function (response) {
                        window.location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function () { }
                });
            }
            catch (err) { }
        }
```

The button is perfectly working in Desktop but it is not working in IPad.

Comment: Do things like `alert`s work within `UpdateInfo()`? Try adding alerts and other indicators to different parts of the flow, so you can make sure each part is running.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to test without an online version of this, but it could be that the event onClick won't work for some touch devices. I would suggest trying to bind the 'tap' event as well as onClick. I would also suggest that you could use the separate .js file to call this function seeing as it has an ID already to help debug (however there could be a good reason you're doing this, no judgement). This is assuming that you mean the function is not being called when you tap this on an iPad, if not please specify the issue and I'll see what the score is.

```
$('#UpdateButton').bind('click',UpdateInfo).bind('tap',UpdateInfo);
```

//edited for typos

Comment: I am unable to catch the issue as IPad does not reflect any error on that button click.

Comment: If you can get access to a mac, you can connect it via USB and, running safari, open up the debugger. You may be able to do this in windows I'm not sure as I only use macOS!

Comment: Tip: As of jQuery 3.0 [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) has been deprecated, it was superseded by the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.